# Solve clauses with multiple pairs of literals in propositional logic

Tags: logic

I'm new to logic and I have the clauses $\{A, B, C\}$ and $\{A, \neg B, \neg C\}$, and I know that in propositional logic I can solve only one pair of literals at a time. However, I don't really know how to apply the statement to the problem.

I've tried with $\{A, B, C\} \{A, \neg B, \neg C\} \implies \{A, C, \neg C\}, \{A, B, \neg B\}$ but I don't think it is right.

What am I missing?

Comment: The law of the excluded middle is a tautology.  Both of those inferences therefore seem fine to me following the resolution rule of inference.

Comment: What you get so far is correct, but by 'Solve clauses', do you mean to check if they are satisfiable, or simplify the expression? If it's checking SAT you can write$$\{A,B,C\},\{A,\lnot B,\lnot C\}\Rightarrow\{A,B,\lnot B\},\{A,C,\lnot C\}\Rightarrow \text{SAT}$$